# Keep user logged in for variable times in flutter with aws amplify and cognito

Tags: flutter, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, access-token, refresh-token

I want the user to decide how long the user will keep logged in the app.
Adding a checkbox “keep me logged in” for e.g 2 days, 15 days, 30 days (as options and whatever maximum is possible) in the login screen when login, will take that value to decide to how long to keep the user logged in.

so when user logs in and choose lets say 2 days to keep user logged in, and sometime later user goes out from the app and reopens it after a day, user should be logged in automatically.
but if user tries this after three days then user should be starting from the login screen.

how can it be done using flutter with aws amplify and cognito services ?